# Traversing up ( parent ) and then down ( child )

Tags: jquery, traversal

I want to achive something like this

```
var argument = $(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().child().attr('ctryid');
```

here is a snip of the section I want to traverse.
I want to go from `newProvButton` to the element with `ctryid`.

its a mess, im sorry.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to find the related parent element with the given selector. Try this:

```
var argument = $(this).closest('.expandListContent').prev().find('.expandListHeaderRow').attr('ctryid');
```

You should also note that using non-spec attributes in your HTML will render your page invalid. Use a `data-*` attribute instead:

```
<div class="expandListHeaderRow" data-ctryid="your-guid">Foo</div>
```

```js
var argument = $(this).closest('.expandListContent').prev().find('.expandListHeaderRow').data('ctryid');
```

Comment: Thank you Rory. and for the tip aswell, did not know that.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo @TusharGupta

Answer (score 1):

You can narrow down the selector using `.closest()`:

```
$(this).closest('.expandListContent').prev().find('div').attr('ctryid');
```

or

```
$(this).closest('.expandListContent').prev().find('.expandListHeaderRow').attr('ctryid');
```

Comment: Thanks Milind, yours works as-well, but for the tip I got from @Rory McCrossan, I think im going for his answer.

Comment: @mornenel: You should morne. :)